# How to populate repetitive sequence number based on 1 batch load

Tags: sql, oracle, oracle-sqldeveloper, sequence

I have the below table-

```
Id   First_Name  Last_Name  Run_Id
1    Alice       Spears      1 
2    Bob         Vance       1
```

I need to populate the Run_id column, where the next batch of data should have value as 2 for all the rows populated in the load. Can we use sequence here, I'm not sure how to achieve this.

The next batch load should look like below-

```
Id   First_Name  Last_Name  Run_Id
1    Alice       Spears      1 
2    Bob         Vance       1
3    Kate        Josh        2
4    Harry       Gough       2
5    Ben         Bohmer      2
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: It's not clear how you would do this in a multi-user environment. If you need a unique identifier for each batch, you should rather store three other columns: user id (for the user loading the batch), session id (assuming the same user may start more than one session in parallel - in most cases they can) and timestamp. Then if you need to give batches sequential numbers, you can - based on this additional data. I believe a more common arrangement is to store just a timestamp - this assumes that two batches wouldn't be loaded exactly at the same time, so two or more batches aren't seen as one.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Create a sequence and a function. Then call the function and save it into a variable and reference the variable while doing your DML.

```
CREATE SEQUENCE batch_seq
  START WITH 1
  MAXVALUE 999999999999999999999999999
  MINVALUE 1
  NOCYCLE
  CACHE 20
  NOORDER;

       CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION get_batch_seq RETURN number AS l_return number;
         BEGIN 
             SELECT batch_seq.nextval into l_return from dual;
            return l_return;
        END;
/



 SELECT get_batch_seq INTO l_batch_seq FROM dual;
```

Comment: @Beefstu- Thanks for your response, this is really helpful. How do I use the declared variable for this function while populating the column?

Comment: DECLARE
  l_batch_seq_num  PLS_INTEGER;
 
BEGIN

…
...

  END;

Comment: @porsh01 did this work out for you? If so can you accept my solution

Comment: @porsh01 did my solution workout for you? If so please upvote it. Thanks